# NetLogo: Changing a heading to the opposite value

Tags: netlogo

I need to calculate how to reverse a heading within a NetLogo script e.g. a turtle has a heading of 0, I need to flip this to 180 so they travel in the opposite direction.

I've tried [360 - heading] with limited success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record `heading - 180` works, of course, but if you want to be more "turtle centric", you could ask your turtle to [`rt 180`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#rt).

Comment: and of course `heading + 180` and `lt 180` are also both equally correct. in my code I would use `rt 180`

Answer (score 2):

Ahh got it. I knew I was close

```
[heading - 180]
```